# How do you burn an ISO image on a Mac?

Tags: mac, iso, optical-media

Is there a utility built into the Mac software to allow for burning ISO downloaded from the internet.

Or..  Is there a better utility on the Net for performing this function?

Thank you,
Keith

Comment: I, for one, am glad this question got answered before Jeff closed it, because I administer Macs and have not previously had the occasion to burn an ISO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Built in Disk Utility can do it.

Comment: its really confusing to use the first time but after you figure it out it makes sense.  I still remember wondering how burning a ISO that way was "easy" but I don't even think about it now

Comment: Worked Great.  Even putting a blank disk into the Mac gave me the option of opening Disk Utility

Answer (score 5):

The steps below show how to use the Disk Utility functionality. (Copied from [Life Hacker](http://lifehacker.com/software/mac-os-x/mac-tip--how-to-burn-an-iso-or-dmg-file-to-disc-251758.php)).

1. Launch Disk Utility (Applications > Utilities).
2. Insert your blank DVD or CD.
3. Drag and drop your .dmg or .iso file to the left pane in Disk Utility. Now both the blank disk and the .iso/.dmg should be listed.
4. Select the .iso/.dmg file you want to burn to disc, and click on the Burn button. A dialog box confirming the destination (your blank CD/DVD) will appear, as shown:
5. Sit back and wait while your new disc gets written!

Alternatively you could use a third party application like [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html)

Comment: Might want to cut-n-past those steps to your answer, in case LH decides to change their link format, etc.

Comment: Good idea. Didn't realise that Life Hacker material was Creative Commons.

Answer (score 2):

Coming with the OS in /Applications/Utilities/ is a program called Disk Utility. You can either click the Burn icon or from the Image menu chose Burn... (Command-B) and then find your ISO.

Alternatives that are available: Roxio's [Toast](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/titanium/overview.html), [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html), and a few others. Toast has the most features (eg. mount an ISO that Disk Utility won't, burn/mount bin/cue files) but costs ~$80 USD.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Disco](http://discoapp.com/) for this and they make it quite easy. However if you want o stick to something built-in I recommend taking a look at these links as I believe there is a way to do such a thing through the Disk Utility:

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9180137

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1464271

http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=DiskUtility/10.5/en/duh3.html